# Best way to upgrade to 12.04

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade Ubuntu to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-ubuntu-to-12-04)

When 12.04 hits on the 26th, what is the best way to upgrade from 11.10 (or any version)? Should I download an ISO and install from CD or upgrade from the update manager? What are the advantages of either?

Keep in mind I want to keep EVERYTHING: my packages, my settings, documents, custom file system configurations, etc.

Also, should I wait until the 26th, or can I go ahead and upgrade to the beta and then upgrade the beta on the 26th?